# What is Last Run Result (0x80042000)?

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task, task-manager

No matter what I do, my task exits with "Last Run Result" 0x80042000.  It claims to pass successfully, but it's not doing anything -- the process appears for an instant and then disappears.  If I do Start/Run and type in the exact same command, then that works fine.  I've setup the same task in Server2003 and it works fine there.  I'm logged in as Administrator, so I don't think UAC is the problem.

I've searched for this code 0x80042000 and it's nowhere to be found.  Anyone know what is means?

Comment: What kind of task is your job? If it's a script, what kind of script?

Comment: Do you have the scheduled task set to run as Administrator, or as some particular user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's what happened:

I was confused by the "Last Run Result", thinking that this was a Server 2008/Task Scheduler return code.  Actually, it's the return code from the application that was run.  So the Task "History" says "successfully finished", but the "Last Run Result" = 0x80042000.

So, once I figured that out, the answer was easy -- this is an InstallShield app and 0x80042000 is the return code for when the app encounters an InstallScript "abort" command.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out for the error codes:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308558

I would guess that you're running into an environment issue that you don't have when run as yourself. Can you post the command you're trying to run? There might be a run silently switch.

Let me know!

Cheers,
-Mathew